# Write in a 2 columns csv with imacros

Tags: csv, firefox, imacros

I'm in my first days using Imacro especially for web scraping content.
I have written a imacro than makes google queries and get the first *Google map* images for this queries.
The macro works and get the images `URL` but I cannot manage to export the data in a proper `CSV` with 2 colums.

What I would like is a csv with 2 colums :

mykeyword; The `URL` scraped.

Here is my macro so far :

```
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074

TAB T=1     

SET !DATASOURCE prefectures.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !LOOP 1

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=https://www.google.fr/search?q={{!COL1}}

SET !EXTRACTADD {{!COL1}} 
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=test.csv

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://*.ggpht.com/* EXTRACT=HREF

URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}

SET !EXTRACTADD {{!COL2}} 
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=test.csv

SET !VAR3 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")

WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR3}}
```

Here are some of the keywords in my original csv file (prefectures.csv)

```
Sous-préfecture de Vouziers
Sous-préfecture de Vire
Sous-préfecture de Villeneuve-sur-Lot
Sous-préfecture de Villefranche-sur-Saône
Sous-préfecture de Villefranche-de-Rouergue
Sous-préfecture de Vierzon
```

What is wrong with my macro to write into 2 columns ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how your macro must look like in order to write the data into 2 columns:

```
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE prefectures.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=https://www.google.fr/search?q={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://.ggpht.com/ EXTRACT=HREF
URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}[EXTRACT]{{!EXTRACT}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ FILE=test.csv
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR3}}
```